# Adding tags to tumblr post via API

Tags: jquery, api, post, tumblr

I'm trying to add tags to a tumblr post with jquery, via the tumblr api.

So far I've called the api as so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/<My Blog>.tumblr.com/post/edit',
    method: 'post',
    data : ({
        api_key :'<My Secret Key>',
    }),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results){

    }
})
```

I've found the location of the tags via get. They're located at

```
results.response.posts[#].tags[#]
```

I've never done an api post before though so I'm not sure what to do at the success function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could use `results.response.posts[#].tags.push("YourNewTag");` or something like that. You'd have to iterate through each post if you want it to apply to all of them of course

Comment: When I try that (tried it with post 0) I get:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: But you're able to read `results.response.posts[0].tags[0]`?

Comment: Looks like I made a mistake in the url. Ending with /posts instead of /post/edit returns the results. I still don't get results when I try the tag push. No console log response at all.

Comment: Are you following [this](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting) and sending the tags as a comma separated parameter?

Comment: I've figured out that I need to use OAuth instead of just my API key for any POST actions (which can't be done in jQuery). Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right you do need to use OAuth to make the request, however there are Javascript Clients (including one for jQuery) which will help you to do this.

Before proceeding though you will need to [register your application](https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps) in order to get the OAuth keys.

The jQuery specific OAuth client can be found [here](https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a) and the function below is adapted from it's documentation.

Information on the other Javascript clients can be found at the [OAuth page](http://oauth.net/code/).

```
    function tagEdit(tagID, tags){

var oauth = OAuth({
    consumer: {
        public: '[public key]',
        secret: '[secret key]'
    },
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1'
});


var request_data = {
    url: 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/[your blog].tumblr.com/post/edit',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        id: tagID, tag: tags
    }
};


var token = {
    public: '[public token]',
    secret: '[public key]'
};


$.ajax({
    url: request_data.url,
    type: request_data.method,
    data: request_data.data,
    headers: oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(request_data, token))
}).done(function(data) {
    //what happens after the post has taken place
});
}
```

NB none of this has been tested as I don't have a tumblr account and I don't fancy registering for OAuth keys. Hope this might be of some use to you though.